# Program fails to execute after startx. Why?

Tags: xorg, raspberry-pi, x-server

I'm using Raspbian Jessie Lite as the OS for RPi 3. This OS does not have `X11` by default, so I installed `xserver-xorg` and `xinit` manually.

I want to play a movie or display a picture after `startx`. So I edit `~/.xinitrc` file as the following:

```
feh /home/pi/mypicture.jpg
```

This works perfectly fine; Every time I execute `startx` on command line, it starts to display the picture.

However, when I edit the `~/.xinitrc` as the following:

```
omxplayer /home/pi/myvideo.mp4
```

unfortunately, after executing `startx`, it does not play video. Using `ssh`, the `top` says that `omxplayer` and `omxplayer.bin` are stopped.

So, how can I execute `omxplayer` right after `startx` !?